# If b = [1, 2, 3, 4], and c = [...b], why doesn't b equal c?

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

The title pretty much says it all, but here it is written out:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4];
c = [...b];

b === c; //false
```

Why?

Comment: `[] !== []`. Two arrays are two unique objects. To compare, you need to iterate.

Comment: @elclanrs To an expert it's obvious this is a duplicate of the mentioned question. To someone who is asking the question it is distinct: you can see this because there is no mention of the `...` operator on the linked page. It's subtle enough I can see it staying closed or being reopened but my vote is for re-opening.

Comment: @LeviMorrison Note, spread syntax `...` is not an operator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper

Comment: @guest271314 Fair enough; I invoked the spec in my answer so I deserve to be nitpicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's how regular array [identity / strict equality comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) works. Remember that arrays are objects:

> ## The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm
>
> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
> 3. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>    - If x is NaN, return false.
>    - If y is NaN, return false.
>    - If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>    - If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
>    - If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
>    - Return false.
> 5. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions); otherwise, return false.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false; otherwise, return false.
> 7. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.
>
> NOTE This algorithm differs from the SameValue Algorithm (9.12) in its treatment of signed zeroes and NaNs.

The `...` has no impact. If we assign the same literals to both we can see this:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4];
c = [1, 2, 3, 4];

b === c; //false
```

This is because each `[]` will create a new array, even if it uses a spread in it.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is a new `Array` instance, not the same object.

You can use `.every()` to check if every element at index of `b` has the same value of element at index `c`

```
let bool = b.every((n, index) => c[index] === n)
```

Comment: See also [3.3.20.\[SameObject\]](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#SameObject). For example `const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
window.speechSynthesis === synth // should always be true`